# Get string from fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was wondering how to get a string from this fetch. I have this code so far, for example, I want the level like

```
message.reply(`Your level is ${level}`)
```

Right now I have this code:

```
if(args[0]) {
  let krunkerName = args[0]
  const api = `https://apiktracer.herokuapp.com/user/${krunkerName}`;

  fetch(api)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));

  message.channel.send() //String here

} else {
  message.reply("Please select a user to check stats on")
}
```

From the `console.log`, I get this right now when i type in a name, in this example `mackex5x5`:

```
{"stats":{"name":"mackex5x5","id":2858585,"score":2921985,"level":51,"levelProgress":28,"kills":25913,"deaths":5309,"kdr":"4.88","kpg":"19.92","spk":"112.76","totalGamesPlayed":1301,"wins":922,"loses":379,"wl":"0.71","playTime":"3d 26m","funds":22280,"clan":false,"featured":"No","hacker":false,"following":0,"followers":3,"shots":186973,"hits":72936,"nukes":71,"meleeKills":59,"createdDate":"2019-04-13","createdTime":"13:06:00","lastPlayedClass":"Marksman"},"uuid":"3e78ef6b-6121-42db-a112-e6757e5d0bf4","error":"False"}
```

Comment: what does the comment `//String here` mean? did you want access to something asynchronous outside of the promise chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `.send` or `.reply` in your `.then` chain.

```
if(args[0]) {
  let krunkerName = args[0]
  const api = `https://apiktracer.herokuapp.com/user/${krunkerName}`;

  fetch(api)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(body => {
       console.log(body)
       message.reply(`Your level is ${body.stats.level}`) //String here
  });

}else{
  message.reply("Please select a user to check stats on")
}
```

Because the `fetch` api is resolving in the future as it is an asynchronous call, so `message.channel.send` or `message.reply` is being called **BEFORE** it resolves.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just asking how you could access data within an object in JavaScript? If so, you should be [converting the `fetch` response to a JavaScript object with `json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (rather than parsing it as `text`):

```js
fetch(api)
  .then(res => res.json()) // change text() to json()
  .then(body => message.reply(`Your level is ${body.stats.level}`));
```

Answer (score -1):

Access the properties of the object being returned using dot syntax. `console.log(body)` would become `console.log(body.stats.level)`.